# Custom Event having same name as native event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener, dispatchevent

First of all, I would like to know whether it is right to create custom event with the same name as native event ?

My requirement is, I want to dispatch a custom event "click" with additional data using Javascript `dispatchEvent`. If I do so, the event is fired twice. My code is given below:

```
 button.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
    if(!event.detail || event.detail && !event.detail.fromComponent){
        let eventObject = new CustomEvent("click", {bubbles: true, composed: true, cancelable: true, detail: {myCustomKey: myCustomValue, fromComponent: true });
    }
 });
```

To avoid infinite looping, I have added boolean key`*fromComponent` in the detail object. Is there any way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Not sure if this will work but instead of having the boolean check can't you just do event.preventDefault() and then do your custom event?

Why compose a custom event if you're already handling the event with the data there? Seems like you could just do what you need to do without the custom event? Absolute worst case, just call it something else. Overriding native events seems like it could get very confusing, don't overcomplicate something for no reason. KISS.

Comment: I have tried both return false and event.preventDefault(). Both doesn't seem to work. I'm building custom web components for which I have custom events having same name as native events where I do some additional processing and dispatch the custom event. For understanding, I have just demonstrated a simple click event on the button.